# Cannot save some fields and an image

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I tried this code to save some fields and an image.
I use MySQL and zzeos for connectinf to the database.

How to fix this code ?

```
procedure Tfbiodata.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  gambar : TMemoryStream;
begin
  if (edtnis.Text='') or (edtname.Text='') or (cmbjk.Text='') or (edtempat.Text='') or (edtgl.Text='') or (cmbtingkatan.Text='') then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Maaf !!! Data Anda Belum Lengkap ....');
    exit;
  end;
  begin
    zbiodata2.Open;
    zbiodata2.Append;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('NIS').AsString := edtnis.Text;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('Nama_siswa').AsString := edtname.Text;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('Jenis_kelamin').AsString := cmbjk.Text;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('Tempat_lahir').AsString :=  edtempat.Text;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('Tanggal_lahir').AsString  := edtgl.Text;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('Tingkatan').AsString :=  cmbtingkatan.Text;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('Hasil_indentifkasi').AsString := lblhasil.Caption;
    zbiodata2.FieldByName('Metode_pembeaaran').AsString := memo1.Text;
    try
      convertobmp(openpicture.FileName);
      gambar := TMemorystream.Create;
      image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(gambar);
      zbiodata2.SQL.Text := 'insert into biodata (gambar) values (:p0)';
      zbiodata2.Params[0].LoadFromStream(gambar,ftBlob);
      zbiodata2.Post;    
      zbiodata2.ExecSQL;
    except
      on E:Exception do
        ShowMessage('sorry this a problem .' + #13 + 'Error : ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When I run this code, I get the error "sorry this is a problem . Error: List index out of bounds(2)"

Comment: You need to indent your code correctly. Which end is from the try, which is from the begin? Also, your begin before zbiodata2.Open; is wrong. What error message you got in the end?

Comment: i find this message " sorry this a problem error list index out of bounds (2)"

Comment: Don't be afraid of exceptions. Raise an exception instead of `ShowMessage( 'Maaf !!! ...' );` and do not catch the exception at the end of your code, because you lost some useful informations on that exception. Only catch exceptions you can handle/fix or you want to translate/extend and raise a new one

Comment: It helps if you tell us what the problem is that you're having. "Can you fix it" without explaining in what way it doesn't work is not a problem description. In the future, please explain the problem so that we have an indication of what we're looking to solve. I've added the exception message from your comment to the question to make it clear what the issue is with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(gambar)`, set `gambar.Position` back to 0 before then calling `zbiodata2.Params[0].LoadFromStream(gambar,ftBlob)`:

```
image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(gambar);
gambar.Position := 0; // <-- add this
zbiodata2.Params[0].LoadFromStream(gambar,ftBlob);
```

With that said, you are using `zbiodata2` for two different operations at the same time - editing a new row that is being appended, and executing an SQL statement.  Don't do that!  Use separate components for each operation.

If the image is being saved into the same row that is being appended, don't bother executing a separate SQL `INSERT` statement at all.  Save the image data directly into the row's `gambar` TField before then calling `zbiodata2.Post()`:

```
procedure Tfbiodata.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  gambar : TStream;
begin
  if (edtnis.Text='') or (edtname.Text='') or (cmbjk.Text='') or (edtempat.Text='') or (edtgl.Text='') or (cmbtingkatan.Text='') then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Maaf !!! Data Anda Belum Lengkap ....');
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    convertobmp(openpicture.FileName);

    zbiodata2.Open;
    zbiodata2.Append;
    try
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('NIS').AsString := edtnis.Text;
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('Nama_siswa').AsString := edtname.Text;
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('Jenis_kelamin').AsString := cmbjk.Text;
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('Tempat_lahir').AsString :=  edtempat.Text;
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('Tanggal_lahir').AsString  := edtgl.Text;
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('Tingkatan').AsString :=  cmbtingkatan.Text;
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('Hasil_indentifkasi').AsString := lblhasil.Caption;
      zbiodata2.FieldByName('Metode_pembeaaran').AsString := memo1.Text;

      if (image1.Picture.Graphic <> nil) and (not image1.Picture.Graphic.Empty) then
      begin
        gambar := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(gambar);
          gambar.Position := 0;
          (zbiodata2.FieldByName('gambar') as TBlobField).LoadFromStream(gambar);
        finally
          gambar.Free;
        end;

        {
        Alternatively:

        gambar := zbiodata2.CreateBlobStream(zbiodata2.FieldByName('gambar'), bmWrite);
        try
          image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(gambar);
        finally
          gambar.Free;
        end;
        }
      end;

      zbiodata2.Post;    
    except
      zbiodata2.Cancel;
      raise;    
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage('sorry this a problem .' + #13 + 'Error : ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

If you are still having problems after that, you need to explain what is actually going wrong, what errors you are seeing, etc.